# How to switch accounts in Diablo Immortal?

Tags: diablo-immortal

I just got into the Diablo Immortal Early Access on the Google Play Store.

Upon installing and playing for the first time, I accidentally tapped 'cancel' on the login screen and was assigned a random identifier.

I cannot find the logout button; deleting the cache and 4GB of downloaded contents didn't help either.

I have also tried Uninstall → Reboot → Install, but I never got to see the battle.net login screen again. It brings me directly to the Character Creation page, and pressing 'Back' shows that I am on an unknown battle.net account.

How can I sign out and then login to my battle.net account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Settings screen, Account, you have the "Log Out" button.

[image: Screenshot of Log Out screen in Diablo Immortal]